# how to print user friendly poker hand in python?

Tags: python

I am writing a poker game in python and I need to print out a poker hand that will be easy to read for a user. It's not printing what i need it to print. I know there is a solution, I just don't see it. Here is the code:

```
userCards = ['AC','KD','4C','4S','7H']
print('Your cards:')
for card in range(len(userCards)):
   print('%s) %-2s of %-9s' % (card,cvalue,csuit))
```

I have already defined the userCards, value and suit. I just need it to print out the hand like this:

> 'Your cards:'
>
> 1) Ace of Spades
>
> 2) King of diamonds
>
> 3)4 of Clubs
>
> 4)4 of Spades
>
> 5)7 of Hearts

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `userCards` look like?

Comment: userCards would look something like:    ['AC, 'KD','4C','4S,'7H']

Comment: Please edit the example `userCards` into your question. Have you defined a `dict` (or some other data structure) to translate `'A'` to `'Ace'`, `'K'` to `'King'`, etc; and one for `'C'` to '`Clubs'`, `'D'` to `'Diamonds'`, etc?

Comment: Yes i have. I have defined functions that return value and suit.

Comment: So then why not call them?

Comment: because when i do and i put it in print function it returns just the last card. And i need it for all the cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using functions that expand the card's rank and suit I suggest using dictionaries. Dictionaries are a compact and efficient way to do this sort of thing.

This code should work on Python 2 or Python 3.

```
from __future__ import print_function

suits = {'C': 'Clubs', 'D': 'Diamonds', 'H': 'Hearts', 'S': 'Spades'}
ranks = {'J': 'Jack', 'Q': 'Queen', 'K': 'King', 'A': 'Ace'}

def show_hand(hand):
    print('Your cards:')
    for rank, suit in hand:
        rank = ranks.get(rank, rank)
        suit = suits[suit]
        print('%s of %s' % (rank, suit))

#Test
userCards = ['AC', 'KD', '4C', '4S', '7H']
show_hand(userCards)
```

**output**

```
Your cards:
Ace of Clubs
King of Diamonds
4 of Clubs
4 of Spades
7 of Hearts
```

---

I suppose I should explain `rank = ranks.get(rank, rank)`.

```
somedict.get(key, default)
```

attempts to look up `key` in `somedict`. If that key is present then the associated value is returned, just as if you did `somedict[key]`. But if the key *isn't* present, then `default` is returned. So `rank = ranks.get(rank, rank)` returns the expanded `rank`, if one exists, otherwise it just returns the original `rank` string. So `A` gets translated to `Ace` but number strings remain as they are.

---

The clean way to get the card's index as well is to use the built-in [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function. We supply a `start` argument of 1 to `enumerate` to get 1-based indices:

```
def show_hand(hand):
    print('Your cards:')
    for i, (rank, suit) in enumerate(hand, 1):
        rank = ranks.get(rank, rank)
        suit = suits[suit]
        print('%d: %s of %s' % (i, rank, suit))
```

**output**

```
Your cards:
1: Ace of Clubs
2: King of Diamonds
3: 4 of Clubs
4: 4 of Spades
5: 7 of Hearts
```

---

Finally, here's a new version that uses the `zip` and `all` functions to detect if a hand contains a flush. If it does, the suit letter is returned, otherwise `None` is returned.

```
from __future__ import print_function

suits = {'C': 'Clubs', 'D': 'Diamonds', 'H': 'Hearts', 'S': 'Spades'}
ranks = {'J': 'Jack', 'Q': 'Queen', 'K': 'King', 'A': 'Ace'}

def show_hand(hand):
    print('Your cards:')
    for i, (rank, suit) in enumerate(hand, 1):
        rank = ranks.get(rank, rank)
        suit = suits[suit]
        print('%d: %s of %s' % (i, rank, suit))

def is_flush(hand):
    #Get suits
    suit_list = zip(*hand)[1]
    #Test if all the cards match the suit of the first card
    suit = suit_list[0]
    return suit if all(s == suit for s in suit_list) else None

#Test
userCards = ['AC', 'KD', '4C', '4S', '7H']
flushCards = '3D 5D AD QD 7D'.split()
hands = (userCards, flushCards)

for hand in hands:
    show_hand(hand)
    suit = is_flush(hand)
    if suit is None:
        print('Not a flush')
    else:
        print('Flush in %s' % suits[suit])
    print()
```

**output**

```
Your cards:
1: Ace of Clubs
2: King of Diamonds
3: 4 of Clubs
4: 4 of Spades
5: 7 of Hearts
Not a flush

Your cards:
1: 3 of Diamonds
2: 5 of Diamonds
3: Ace of Diamonds
4: Queen of Diamonds
5: 7 of Diamonds
Flush in Diamonds
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation :) i really appreciate it.

Comment: How can i get it to print the index of the list too?

Comment: thanks. one more question. I've been trying to define flush but im missing something. Can you help me please :)

Comment: @katja92: Maybe. :) But I think you should start a new question. Link it to this one if you like.

Comment: can't do. apparently i've asked too many question which some people didn't like. I'll update this one.

Comment: @katja92: Please don't do that! SO questions should contain a single question, and they should not be modified substantially after they've already received an answer. That policy ensures that your question not only helps you, it also maximizes its benefit for future readers with a similar problem.

Comment: then how should i do this?

Comment: @katja92 Thanks for rolling back your edit. I'll add a simple flush detection function to my answer in a little while.

Comment: @katja92: No, I don't need your code. In the mean time, please read [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478) to understand the Stack Exchange attitude towards questions that keep changing as they get answered.

Comment: @katja92: There you go. But that's **definitely** the last update I'm making to this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.