# How to convert string value into int value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a game of blackjack in python.Like a 7s value is a 7 but, a jacks value is a 10 so:

```
cards = ['ace','king','queen'....'3','2'

firstCard = random.choice(cards)

secondCard = random.choice(cards); remove.cards(firstCard)

print(int(firstCard) + int(secondCard))
```

## Works perfectly for number

how could I do it for kings or aces...

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36662115/4014959

Answer (score 6):

You can use a dictionary, keys are `'ace'`, `'king'`, `'queen'`, and values are corresponding numeric values. Based on the rule of your game, you can mapping the keys and values as you intend to.

```
mydict = {"ace": 1, "king": 13, "queen": 12}

num_of_queen = mydict["queen"]  # gets the numeric value
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary can help !

```
cards =  {1:"ace": 1, 13:"king", 12:"queen"}

firstCard = random.choice(cards.keys())

secondCard = random.choice(cards.keys()); 

remove.cards(firstCard)

print(firstCard + secondCard)
```

To get the name of the card, you can:

```
cards[firstCard]
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to wrap a regular dictionary in a class to make it a little easier to use:

```
class BlackJackDeck:
    class NoSuchCard(Exception):
        pass

    values = {'king': 10,
              'jack': 10,
              'queen': 10,
              'ace-high': 11,
              'ace-low': 1}
    values.update(zip(range(2, 11), range(2, 11)))

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            item = int(item)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            item = item.lower()

        try:
            return self.values[item]
        except KeyError:
            raise self.NoSuchCard
```

Demo:

```
>>> d = BlackJackDeck()
>>> d[2]
2
>>> d['7']
7
>>> d['KING']
10
>>> d['ace-high']
11
>>> d[100]
[...]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...", line 21, in __getitem__
    raise self.NoSuchCard
d.NoSuchCard
```

This allows you to look up cards by integer- or by string-key, does not care about capitalization and throws a meaningful exception when a card does not exist.